# sql server 2012 - can't grant on select on multi-statement table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, function, user-defined-functions, sql-grant, role

It's my first question here, so I say: hallo!

I have a multi-statement table-valued function (called fn) which (of course) returns a table.
I also created a database role (called dbr).

I tried to add permission 
my dbr can select from my fn.

So I opened the dbr, add my fn to securables, grant on Select and I get an error: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key (mscorelib)

This is little strange, cause in my fn I have primary key on return-table-variable and also key cannot be null. To be specific key is build with three fields: dateFrom, dateTo, article

Function works perfectly, but I cannot make it available to my dbr members.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Were you aware of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql

Comment: Function and same as stored procedure, should grant execute permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's a bug of non-patched Management Studio or you click in a wrong place, why don't you use T-SQL instead?

```
grant select on dbo.fn to dbr
```

Comment: You're right it is probably missing patch problem - I'm not the server admin. So, finnaly it works with T-SQL and not with SQL MS.Thanks!